# Can I denote $f'(g(x))=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}(g(x))} f(g(x))$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

> Can I denote $f'(g(x))=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}(g(x))} f(g(x))$?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Statement) avoids this by letting $y=f(u), u=g(x)$ and then denoting $f'(g(x))=\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}u}$.

Comment: It is not standard notation and it can be confused to be a [functional derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative). IMO it should be avoided. An alternative and compact notation is $\left.\frac{df(t)}{dt}\right|_{t = g(x)}$